# Kibbudim for Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur

Tags: yom-kippur, rosh-hashanah-new-year, gabbai

I'm looking for a list of every time the Aaron kodesh gets opened and closed on RH and YK. Ideally I'd also really appreciate page numbers in the Artscroll or Koren siddurim.
I'm making cards to facilitate easier handing out of the kibbudim.

Does anyone happen to have these handy?

Comment: There are different minhagim. Even among Ashkenazi or sefard itself. It should say in the siddur you're using though

Comment: The easier solution is have one person be in charge and just stand there the whole time letting the rest of us focus on our davening. Usually there is a gabbai, rabbi, or president that stands right near there anyway.

Comment: @Shababnik More like there were different minhagim. Then everyone just did what was printed in the machzor and forgot their tradition. Then they bought a new machzor and did like that one since the typeface was nicer so it must know better about minhagim.

Comment: @DoubleAA unfortunately that is the case, so if unsure just follow the siddur. As is seemingly the case here. Though there are select few who remember their minhagim

Comment: @Shababnik No, if unsure find someone who does know and talk to them. Do not accept some printing and forget about it.

Comment: @DoubleAA agreed. The op didn't specify the minhag though. This should be a question for the rav of the shul or another member who remembers the minhag

Comment: @Shababnik Only if the rav actually knows or finds out. A rav who doesn't know and in being too lazy to learn tells you to follow some printing will in the future be brought to justice for failing as a rav and in the meantime his "psak" isn't even binding. Alas woe to our leaders that such is too common nowadays.

Comment: @DoubleAA Then let the op specify the minhag so someone here might help and not just give him generic cards

Comment: @Shababnik Amen to that, brother!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are existing cards ready to be printed, in Hebrew, updated every year. They follow nusach sfard and the Rinat Israel siddur. I hope they are easy to adapt to your needs

- the version for Rosh Hashana is [here](https://www.babakama.co.il/downloads/item/id/16#prettyPhoto)
- the version for Yom Kippur is [here](https://www.babakama.co.il/downloads/item/id/35)

Comment: These are great, thanks!  I'm going to leave the question open just in case someone has for Ashkenaz Artscroll or Koren.